# opencart 2.0.3.1 to 2.3.0.2 error

Tags: php, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I got this error after up-gradation. Can anybody help me.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: Could
>   not load model total!' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\deleteme\system\engine\loader.php:169 Stack trace: #0
>   [internal function]: Loader->{closure}(Array, Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\deleteme\system\engine\proxy.php(25):
>   call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\deleteme\catalog\controller\common\cart.php(37):
>   Proxy->__call('getTotal', Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\deleteme\catalog\controller\common\cart.php(37):
>   Proxy->getTotal(Array) #4 [internal function]:
>   ControllerCommonCart->index(Array) #5
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\deleteme\system\engine\action.php(51):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #6
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\deleteme\system\engine\loader.php(24):
>   Action->execute(Object(Registry), Array) #7
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\deleteme\catalog\controller\common\header.php(129):
>   Loader->controller('common/cart') #8 [internal function]:
>   ControllerCommonHeader->index(Array) #9
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\deleteme\system\engine\action.php(51):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #10 C:\xampp\ in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\deleteme\system\engine\loader.php on line 169

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upgrade issue is a bug reported and solution explained in their forum, [here](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=191&t=166012).

Summary (copy/paste for posternity):

> BUG: Error: Could not load model total!
>
> Two-part bug. Part one: Event Compatibility cuts off too many parts of
>   the route when trying to load the older extension format. ex.
>   "extension/total/sub_total/getTotal" route gets turned into
>   "total/sub_total" instead of "total/sub_total/getTotal". This causes
>   it to try and load a model with no name throwing the exception. Part
>   Two, this compatibility is being loaded fine when the route is
>   "extension/total/subtotal" but is also loading when the route is
>   "extension/total/sub_total/getTotal". I think this event should not be
>   triggered for compatibility because it is a getTotal is a function
>   call, not a model load. This causes the verification to fail and try
>   to load the 2.2.x version which has other bits missing and throws
>   different errors. Haven't figured out why the function call is going
>   down the event path. But basically the attempt to support backwards
>   compatibility with 2.2 mods is causing problems.
>
> 2 Solutions
>
> FIX 1: Give up on 2.2.x compatibility and delete the following
>   left-over folders:

```
     catalog/model/total
     catalog/model/payment
     catalog/controller/payment
     catalog/model/shipping
     catalog/controller/module
     admin/controller/total
     admin/controller/payment
     admin/controller/shipping
     admin/controller/module
```

> FIX 2: Add a hack to bypass the event when the function call for
>   "getTotal", "getMethod", or "getQuote" are passed in. This is
>   experimental but should at least restore support for 2.2.x mods for
>   now. This is NOT a permanent fix. Just a work around. 
>   EDIT: catalog/controller/event/compatibility.php FIND:

```
'model/' . $route. '.php'
```

> REPLACE WITH:

```
'model/' . ((strpos($route,'get') !== false) ? dirname($route) : $route) . '.php'
```

> This should let routes like "extension/total/sub_total" work but block
>   "extension/total/sub_total/getTotal" calls which fail on the directory
>   check.